# How do I disable or blacklist an Ansible callback plugin?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for a way to disable or blacklist an Ansible callback plugin.

So far it seems that Ansible is loading any callback plugins it finds in paths and there is no way to tell it skip loading a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible provides a [`callback-whitelist`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#callback-whitelist) parameter to enable specific callback plugins.

You can't blacklist, but you can "*tell it skip loading a plugin*" by not including it on the list.

---

This is a confusing claim:

> it seems that Ansible is loading any callback plugins it finds in paths

The docs state the opposite (and it's verifiable):

> Now Ansible ships with all included callback plugins ready to use but they are disabled by default.

You might be using a pre 2.0 version or something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to blacklist plugins.

But if you have control over plugin's source code, you can mark it as `CALLBACK_NEEDS_WHITELIST`.
See example in [slack](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d31ba7240f07e4943d83792b4cb6109df3a1f8ce/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py#L60) callback plugin.

This way the plugin will be disabled unless you add it to whitelist.